# Generate Filename Before Downloading

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, chef-infra

I'm trying to download the latest backup of data during my chef run but it's trying to download the file before the filename is generated. What's the best approach for doing this. All I want to do is generate a filename based on the time and download it.

The below code gives the error `undefined method 'latest_backup' for Custom resource aws_s3_file from cookbook aws.`

```
ruby_block "generate file name" do
  block do
    require 'time'
    latest_backup = "NOT-SET"
    utc_now = Time.now.utc
    utc_midday = Time.new(Time.new.year, Time.new.month, Time.new.day, 22, 00, 1 ).utc
    utc_midnight = Time.new(Time.new.year, Time.new.month, Time.new.day, 10, 00, 1 ).utc
    if (utc_now < utc_midday) && (utc_now > utc_midnight )
      latest_backup = "data_" + Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d") + "-00001.tgz"
    elsif (utc_now > utc_midday ) && (utc_now < utc_midnight)
      latest_backup = "data_" + Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d") + "-120001.tgz"
    end
  end
  action :create
end

aws_s3_file "/root/backup.tgz" do
  remote_path "backup-dir/#{latest_backup}"
  bucket "my-backups-bucket"
  region "ap-southeast-2"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a local variable across contexts like that. Since nothing in that code requires waiting until converge time, you can just run the code outside of a `ruby_block` and have it be a normal local variable.

Comment: I tried it that way previous and didn't work so I tried using ruby_block and I had the same issue. I had a file naming issue 00001 instead of 000001.  Missing one zero in the file name. Thanks for the help though